# Oracle Apex 4.2 Mobile Application Issues

Tags: javascript, oracle, oracle11g, oracle-apex

After Updating my previous oracle apex installation to `Oracle Apex 4.2` i got some errors. (when developing Mobile Applications).

```
 1). Check Boxes doesn't display in Classic Reports.
 2). javascript:redirect() function didn't work.
 3). I have wrote some JavaScript functions to call when button clicked. also they didn't work.
```

In above `2 and 3` situations, i got error as `Uncaught ReferenceError: redirect is not defined`.

PS: Currently i'm upgrading my apex 4.1 application to apex 4.2 with apex mobile template. JavaScript functions works without any errors in my previous version.

How cloud i solve these problems ?

Comment: 1) How do you display your checkboxes in your classic reports ?
2) I suggest you not to use directly the apex internal JavaScript functions. If you want to redirect to an url use `window.location` or `location.href`.
3) Can you show us some code and how/where do you call it? And notice that jQuery has been updated to version 1.7.1 and jQueryUI to version 1.8.22 so be aware of not using some deprecated functions.

We will upgrade to apex 4.2 tomorrow, and I use the same functionnalities (checkboxes in classic reports, JavaScript on button click, etc.) so maybe I will be able to help you more.

Comment: @Yann39 In some reports nothing displayed for check boxes. but in some reports check boxes displayed as unclickable ellipse.